# Finding filenames in a folder that contain a variable from a list, opening the JSON files and performing actions on them

Tags: python

I'm working with JSON filetypes and I've created some code that will open a single file and add it to a pandas dataframe, performing some procedures on the data within, snipper of this code as follows;

```
response_dic=first_response.json()   
print(response_dic)
base_df=pd.DataFrame(response_dic)
base_df.head()
```

The code then goes on to extract parts of the JSON data into dataframes, before merging and printing to CSV.

Where I want to develop the code, is to have it iterate through a folder first, find filenames that match my list of filenames that I want to work on and then perform the functions on those filenames. For example, I have a folder with 1000 docs, I will only need to perform the function on a sample of these.
I've created a list in CSV of the account codes that I want to work on, I've then imported the csv details and created a list of account codes as follows:

```
csv_file=open(r'C:\filepath','r')
cikas=[]
cikbs=[]
csv_file.readline()
for a,b,c in csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=','):
    cikas.append(a)
    cikbs.append(b)

midstring=[s for s in cikbs]

print(midstring)
```

My account names are then stored in midstring, for example ['12345', '2468', '56789']. This means I can control which account codes are worked on by amending my CSV file in future. These names will vary at different stages hence I don't want to absolutely define them at this stage.

What I would like the code to do, is check the working directory, see if there is a file that matches for example C:\Users*12345.json. If there is, perform the pandas procedures upon it, then move to the next file. Is this possible? I've tried a number of tutorials involving glob, iglob, fnmatch etc but struggling to come up with a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can list all the files with `.json` extension in the current directory first.

```
import os, json
import pandas as pd

path_to_json = 'currentdir/'
json_files = [json_file for json_file in os.listdir(path_to_json) if json_file.endswith('.json')]
print(json_files)
```

Now iterate over the list of json_files and perform a check

```
# example list json_files= ['12345.json','2468.json','56789.json']
# midstring = ['12345', '2468, '56789']

for file in json_files:
   if file.split('.')[0] in midstring:
      df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_file)
      # perform pandas functions
   else:
       continue
```

Comment: Thanks, however I have 1000 files which are JSON. What I want to do is say select the handful of files where the account code in their file name, is held in my string which I’ve taken from my CSV file. 

So in the string from csv, it holds multiple account codes. Can I pass them into the function to say in path, if filename contains values from string, then do X

Comment: The account code should be in some format of a serial number if you want a handful of files because if they are unique then you got to iterate over one by one.